# Connection timeout with rsync

Tags: services, rsync

I'm trying to connect to a machine that has `rsync` setup as a daemon, and I constantly receive:

```
rsync: failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX): Connection timed out (110)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

Do I have to setup rsync as a daemon on my machine in order to connect to the server that has rsync as a daemon on it?

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the rsync service is running on the remote machine and that the listening port (873 by default) is open (i.e. your client is not being blocked by a firewall)?

Comment: I cannot confirm that at this point, since I'm not the owner of the machine. But I suspect it's firewall. I've setup my test server and enabled rsync as daemon, and connect to it without problem (and without having to setup on my machine anything). I guess the answer to my question is that I don't need rsync daemon on my machine in order to connect to it.

Comment: That's correct AFAIK - you could try a basic port connectivity test with telnet for example i.e. `telnet 873` and look for a return string something like `@RSYNCD: X.Y`